# Problema al cambiar el valor de un textinput

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente función la cual la llamo tanto por teclado como por un href simulando un botón pero el detalle pasa porque cuando la ejecuto por teclado cambia el valor de ('#total') pero cuando la ejecuto por clic no lo hace.

```
function calcular_total(){

        $('#items tr').each(function () {
            var cantidad = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
            var precio = $(this).find('td').eq(3).html();
            if(typeof cantidad != 'undefined' && typeof precio != 'undefined')
            {
                var cantidad = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
                var precio2 = $(this).find('td').eq(3).html();
                var preciocorregido = parseFloat(precio2);
                var cantidadcorregido = parseInt(cantidad);
                var total1 = cantidadcorregido * preciocorregido;
                var total = parseFloat($('#totaloculto').val());
                total += parseFloat(total1);
                $('#totaloculto').val(total);
                $('#total').text(total);
            }
        });
    };
```

De esta manera lo llamo por teclado

```
$('#precio').keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which == 43){
            agregar_item();
            //e.preventDefault();
        };
    });
```

y de esta manera lo llamo por el

```
<a onClick="agregar_item(); return false;" class="btn-floating green btn-large"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
```

La funcion agregar_item() llama a la función calcular total he comprobado que hace todo menos cambiar el valor del inputtext '#total'

Comment: No entendí bien lo de la ejecutada por teclado, a qué te refieres con esa parte? Está soportada por código o simplemente navegas por tabulador y usas Enter?

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código del botón/imagen/enlace que hace la llamada a `calcular_total`?¿Puede haber algún otro elemento que por su posicionamiento esté bloqueando el click? (eso explicaría que funcionase desde teclado pero no haciendo click)

Comment: Cambia `onClick` por `onclick`, todo en minúsculas

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a lanzar el evento así:

```
<a onclick="return agregar_item();">...</a>
```

O así:

```
<a href="javascript:agregar_item();">...</a>
```

Como aclaración, comentar que el comportamiento predeterminado la etiqueta `<a>` es en primer lugar ejecutar el `onclick`, y a continuación seguir el `href` siempre y cuando el `onclick` no devuelva `false`.

También podrías añadir el evento al `<a>` via JavaScript:

```
var button = document.querySelector('tu_selector_para_a')
button.addEventListener('click', agregar_item, false)
```

Saludos y suerte!

Comment: Lo he probado con evento y tampoco funciona

Answer (score 1):

En tu codigo por que repites dos veces cantidad y precio, prueba escribirlo así:

```
function calcular_total(){

        $('#items tr').each(function () {
            var cantidad = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
            var precio = $(this).find('td').eq(3).html();
            if(typeof cantidad != 'undefined' && typeof precio != 'undefined')
            {
                var preciocorregido = parseFloat(precio);
                var cantidadcorregido = parseInt(cantidad);
                var total = parseFloat(cantidadcorregido * preciocorregido);
                total += parseFloat($('#totaloculto').val());
                $('#totaloculto').val(total);
                $('#total').text(total);
            }
        });
    };
```

Mira esta respuesta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick

Mira este sitio también: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp